# jquery event handler - new handler firing too early

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$('.icon-pencil').on('click',function(){
   $(this).removeClass('icon-pencil').addClass('icon-ok');
});
$('.fatherdiv').on('click','.icon-ok',function(){
    alert('test ok event');
});
```

What I want is: If i click on icon-pencil, it should change to icon-ok. But here, it is changing but also firing at the same time the icon-ok event already (alerting `"test ok event"`). why is it happenning? I want it to happend only after changing, not while changing.

my html:

```
<div class="fatherdiv"><i class="icon-pencil"> </i></div>
```

Comment: Why do you even have two event listeners for essentially the same thing? That seems odd

Comment: @mituw16 there are two things. ok and pencil icons. i have different events for each one

Comment: *"why is it happenning?"* Because at the moment the event reaches `.fatherdiv`, the `.icon-pencil` element already has the new class, hence the delegation selector matches and the handler is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really quite odd, and I think it's counter-intuitive behaviour by jQuery -- perhaps even a bug. The problem is that the element is treated as matching the selector for the purposes of the second event handler, even though it didn't when the event was triggered.

This is a bit of a kludge,  but it does fix the problem in this narrow instance:

```
$(document.body).on('click','.icon-pencil',function(){
   $(this).removeClass('icon-pencil').addClass('icon-ok');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9V2ne/)

In this, we attach the event listener higher up the tree than the original  delegated event, so the element is not modified until after the check for that handler.

But as I say, this is surprising behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it by delegating both events:

```
$('.fatherdiv')
    .on('click', '.icon-pencil', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('icon-pencil').addClass('icon-ok');
    })
    .on('click', '.icon-ok', function () {
        alert('test ok event');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably cleanest to do everything in 1 handler:

```
$('.fatherdiv').on('click','i',function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("icon-ok")){
        alert('test ok event');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('icon-pencil').addClass('icon-ok');
    }
});
```